# .NET How to NOT authenticate if provided user from OIDC is not available in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, openid-connect

So my .NET Core WebApplication is logging in an user via Azure AD and I have a database with users and their roles.

I created already OIDC MiddleWare to add Claims from my database for the user that tries to log in.

So the flow is:

- I login with my AD account
- I get the email address and check in the database for it's role
- **Now if the user is blocked or not assigned, the login should fail**

So my question: Is there a way how I could deny the authentication for the user, when he is not available in the DB or blocked?

What I did now is that I set a Claim and if that claim is not available it will be redirected to Access Denied page (by using the AuthorizationPolicy), but I want that the user will be redirected to the login page from Microsoft/AD (in best case with a message).

Is that possible somehow and if so, how ?

This is my code now:

```
 services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
     .AddAzureAD(options => { Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options); }
 );

 services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
 {
   var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .RequireAssertion(context =>
                {
                    Claim claim = context.User.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == ClaimTypes.Expired);
                    return context.User.HasClaim(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Expired) &&
                           context.User.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == ClaimTypes.Expired).Value
                               .Equals("false", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                })
                .RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Name)
                .RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role)
                .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        });

 // OIDC Middleware, to access the User's Claims while logging in through AzureAD
        services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
        {
            options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
            {
                OnRemoteFailure = ctx =>
                {
                    ctx.Response.Redirect("/");
                    ctx.HandleResponse();
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                },
                OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect = ctx =>
                {
                    ctx.Response.Redirect("/");
                    ctx.HandleResponse();
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                },
                OnTokenValidated = ctx =>
                {
                    // Get the user's email 
                    var email = ctx.Principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;

                    // Query the database to get the role
                    using (var db = ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<TracingContext>())
                    {
                        // Get the Users from the database, with the logged in email address (from Azure)
                        User user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UPN.Equals(email));

                        if (user != null)
                        {
                            user.LastLogin = DateTime.Now;
                            db.SaveChanges();

                            // Add claims
                            var claims = new List<Claim>
                            {
                                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.Role.ToString()),
                                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Expired, (!user.IsActivated || user.IsBlocked).ToString())
                            };

                            // Save the claim
                            var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);
                            ctx.Principal.AddIdentity(appIdentity);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                           **// Send back to Login Page (with error message, maybe?)**
                        }
                    }
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                },
            };
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the default processing and handle the response yourself:

```
// Send back to Login Page (with error message, maybe?)
ctx.HandleResponse();
ctx.Response.Redirect("/path/to/login");
```

The call to [`HandleResponse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.basecontrolcontext.handleresponse?view=aspnetcore-1.1) signals that we want to handle the response ourselves and the following call sets up the redirect. There are a few approaches to sending over an error message. One  approach is to provide a query-string parameter to the login URL.

Comment: I tried this already, but I think the token will not be deleted and so it still logs in no ?

Comment: And in which event should I check if the user exists in the database? because now i am doing it in the OnTokenValidated Event, but I think at that point the user is logged in already, no ?

Comment: This solution, using `OnTokenValidated`, is the way to do it. The user will be logged in to the Azure AD tenant, but not into _your_ web application. You need to do it here because only then do you know which user it is.

Comment: When I try to do this, I end up in a loop in the Microsoft login page

Comment: I end up in the login screen after many many redirects and then it says: 
We couldn't sign you in. Please try again.
The result is, i need to clear all the cookies, to be able to login again

Comment: Yeah, that'll be because you 1. Log in to AAD. 2. Return back to your app's login page. 3. This time, you're logged in, so you go straight back to your app. 4. Get sent back to AAD. Repeat from 3. You might prefer to send the user back to an access-denied page in your event handler. If AAD supports it, this access-denied page can allow the user to log out of AAD and then try again with a different account.